# Error when add WebService ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

When I run WCF, it throws the below error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from localhost:3682/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: localhost:3682/Service1.svc Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'localhost:3682/Service1.svc'. There was no endpoint listening at localhost:3682/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3682HTTP GET Error URI: localhost:3682/Service1.svc There was an error downloading 'localhost:3682/Service1.svc'. Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3682**

This is my **Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Shop_DTBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/shop_DTB.csdl|res://*/shop_DTB.ssdl|res://*/shop_DTB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Shop_DTB;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=1234567;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength ="262144" executionTimeout="103600"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>


        <services>
            <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
            <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
                <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
                <endpoint contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                    <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <!--<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**IService:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using Entities;
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Product_Categories> GetAllCategory();
        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProductBestSeller(int idCategory);

        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProByProtype_ID(int idProducttype);

        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProByCate_ID(int idCate);

        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Product_Type> GetAllProductType();
    }
}
```

**Webservice1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using BAL;
using Entities;
namespace WcfService1
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product_Categories> GetAllCategory()
        {
            return new CategoryBAL().GetAllCategoryBAL();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductBestSeller(int idCategory)
        {
            return new ProductBAL().GetProductBestSeller_BAL(idCategory);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProByProtype_ID(int idProducttype)
        {
            return new ProductBAL().GetProByProtype_ID_BAL(idProducttype);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProByCate_ID(int idCate)
        {
            return new ProductBAL().GetProByCate_ID_BAL(idCate);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product_Type> GetAllProductType()
        {
            return new TypeBAL().GetAllProductType();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Detailed error but no source code displayed, you hope that someone help you ? No one can.

Comment: You'r trying to test it in local host ? Maybe it,s the reason why it dosen't work.

Comment: Ok, It worked yesterday , did you add something today or you just opened it and it just didn't work on the first run ?

Comment: I didn't add new anything today. it just didn't work on the first run

Comment: Then i would say it is the Service itself that is down today, can you verify ?

Comment: OK. Can you speak clear  ?

Comment: First, what are you doing ? Adding a web service to your WCF application ? programming a web service ?

Comment: ??¿¿  Good luck learning English...

Comment: I don't understand your question. please ask again ? Excuse me, my english is not well

Comment: Make sure that the WCF service is up and running/active before adding a reference or consuming it.